# How to delete a directory with guarantee in java / scala

Tags: java, scala, io, directory, delete-file

I was initially using something like this but many a times the directories(not empty) are not deleted actually.

```
def delete_file(file: File): Unit = {
    for (i <- 1 to 1000) {
      if (file.exists()) {
        Thread.sleep(60000L)
        try {
          FileUtils.forceDelete(file)
        } catch {
          case ex: NullPointerException => logger.info(s"${file.getAbsolutePath} workspace not deleted due to NPE => ${ex}")
          case ex: FileNotFoundException => logger.info(s"${file.getAbsolutePath} workspace not deleted due to FileNotFoundException => ${ex}")
          case ex: IOException => logger.info(s"${file.getAbsolutePath} workspace not deleted due to IOException => ${ex}")
          case ex: Throwable => logger.info(s"${file.getAbsolutePath} workspace not deleted due to Throwable => ${ex}")
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "guarantee"; it's always going to be possible to fail a delete.  For example: perhaps you don't have write permission on the directory you're trying to delete.

Comment: By guarantee i mean even if we have permission (777) then can we delete surely, even if it is held by some other thread's locks or something else like some file i/o is happening in the file.

Comment: @RaghvendraSingh Your OS might not allow you to delete a directory which is in use without killing the process using it. e.g. Windows.

Comment: @PeterLawrey is there some way to actually get the lock on file away from the process currently having it, and then delete

Comment: @RaghvendraSingh it will be OS specific.

Comment: @RaghvendraSingh yes, kill the process. Often Windows just asks you to reboot the machine.

Comment: @PeterLawrey i want to do it through code on linux, how to know which process is having the lock?

Comment: @RaghvendraSingh On Linux, you don't need to as Linux doesn't prevent deleting files/directories in use.

Comment: @PeterLawrey that does not look like to be the case, since the files are not getting deleted i am doing this amazons linux ec2 boxes